# A method can't read array elements from main method. Why?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Cars[] cars = new Cars[5];
    cars[0] = new Cars("BMW", 318, "SomeText");

    carDetails(0);
}

private static void carDetails( int index ) {
    System.out.println( cars[index].getName() + " "
                        + cars[index].getModel() + " "
                        + cars[index].getSomeText());
}
```

I got a seperated Car class with a constructor(String, int, String)
and fields and accessors. I cant compile this because I got error
in carDetails method. (cars[index]....) It says:

cannot find symbol
symbol: variable car
location: clas Main

Whhy I can't see cars elements in carDetails method?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: it's `cars[0]`, not `car[0]`. You never defined the `car` variable.

Comment: if you need to access cars outside of the main method, declare them as static and at the class level, your current cars array only exists inside the main method, and then its gone.

Comment: It was just typing error! I fixed it now.

Comment: Move `Cars[] cars = new Cars[5];` line outside the main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in one method can't see variables in another method. If you need the variables accessible elsewhere, make them static members of your class.

```
class Foo {
    private static Car[] cars;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         cars = new Car[5];
         cars[0] = new Car("BMW", 318, "SomeText");
         carDetails(0);
    }
    private static void carDetails( int index ) {
       System.out.println( cars[index].getName() + " "
                    + cars[index].getModel() + " "
                    + cars[index].getSomeText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `cars` is defined locally in method main and it is not visible/accessible in method `carDetails()` . You can make the variable static by defining it outside like

```
static Cars[] cars = new Cars[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to:

```
 private static void carDetails(Cars[] cars, int index )
 carDetails(cars, 0);
```

Then pass in the cars as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simple pass that parameter to the method

```
private static void carDetails(  Cars cars ) {
System.out.println( cars.getName() + " "
                    + cars.getModel() + " "
                    + cars.getSomeText());
}
```

From the main call this method like

```
 carDetails(cars[0]);
```

Comment: Why not passing `Car` instance instead of array and index?

Comment: @marsh hot is static keeping it simple there are a ton of disadvantage of static making him use that is not correct

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you must pass the array as parameter to the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Cars[] cars = new Cars[5];
    cars[0] = new Cars("BMW", 318, "SomeText");

    carDetails(0, cars);
}

private static void carDetails( int index, Cars[] cars ) {
    System.out.println( cars[index].getName() + " "
                        + cars[index].getModel() + " "
                        + cars[index].getSomeText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because cars is declared in main method, and only is visible inside. For visibility ouside you should pass it in a parameter to carsDetail function or declare it like a static member in the class.

```
static Cars[] cars = new Cars[5];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    cars[0] = new Cars();
    carDetails(0);
}

private static void carDetails(int index) {
    System.out.println(cars[index].getName() + " "
            + cars[index].getModel() + " "
            + cars[index].getSomeText());
}
```

or

```
static Cars[] cars = new Cars[5];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    cars[0] = new Cars();
    carDetails(cars, 0);
}

private static void carDetails(Cars[] cars, int index) {
    System.out.println(cars[index].getName() + " "
            + cars[index].getModel() + " "
            + cars[index].getSomeText());
}
```